# How to click on the element as per the html through VBScript and Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, vbscript, webdriver

I'm using VbScript with Selenium driver to connect to Chrome (store.steampowered.com/app/681530/NOISZ/) and want to click the "Next in Queue" button which is a div class, but nothing happens. I know I'm on the right track because the below lines does work as expected:

(Displays the text Next in queue)

```
msgbox(driver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[@class='next_in_queue_area']/div[@class='btn_next_in_queue btn_next_in_queue_trigger']").Item(1).text)
```

(Scrolls to the Next in queue button)

```
driver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[@class='next_in_queue_area']").Item(1).ScrollIntoView
```

(But trying these ones does nothing and also no error messages)

```
driver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[@class='queue_actions_ctn']").Item(1).Click
driver.FindElementsByClass("next_in_queue_content").Item(1).Click
```

Using Chrome's Inspect when highligtning this code the Next button is highlighted entirely:

```
<div class="btn_next_in_queue btn_next_in_queue_trigger" data-tooltip-text="Remove this product from your queue and continue to the next item.">
                                    <div class="next_in_queue_content">
                                                                                        <span>Next in Queue<br>
                                                <span class="queue_sub_text">(11 remaining )</span>
                                            </span>
                                                                                </div>
                                </div>
```

So it is just a question of finding the correct div or span to click

Comment: Perhaps I don't find a **"Next in Queue" button** on `store.steampowered.com/app/681530/NOISZ/`. Am I missing something?

Comment: You have to be logged into steam, scroll down to "YOUR DISCOVERY QUEUE" and start the queue, then the button will appear.

Answer (score 0):

To click the button with text as **Next in Queue** you can use either of the following solution:

- `FindElement` with `XPath`:

  ```
  driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='btn_next_in_queue btn_next_in_queue_trigger']/div[@class='next_in_queue_content']/span").Click
  ```
- `FindElements` with `XPath`:

  ```
  driver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[@class='btn_next_in_queue btn_next_in_queue_trigger']/div[@class='next_in_queue_content']/span").Item(1).Click
  ```

As an alternative you can use the `ExecuteScript()` method as follows:

```
Dim js As IJavaScriptExecutor = TryCast(driver, IJavaScriptExecutor)
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[starts-with(@id, 'button-')][@class='x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-center']"))
```

Or

```
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Extensions
driver.ExecuteJavaScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[starts-with(@id, 'button-')][@class='x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-center']"))
```